# show different slice text compared to legend in google pie chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I want to show slightly changed text on each google pie chart slice.

In above below you will see we have legends as

**work,eat,commute,watch tv,sleep**

and we have same text on slices

**work,eat,commute,watch tv,sleep**

all i want is show different text on each slice
e.g.

**work-daily,eat-3times,commute-once a day,watch tv-daily,sleep-daily**

but legends text should remain as mentioned above.

I don't have option to draw legends outside the chart using jquery.

Any help will be appreciated.

```js
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities',
            pieSliceText: 'label',
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>
       <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `pieSliceText` (this is for showing the piechart in separated slices and can give weird results if not used correctly), then add an extra column that defines the tooltips :

```js
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
data.addColumn('number', 'Hours per Day');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});    
data.addRows([
   ['Work', 11, 'work-daily'],
   ['Eat', 2, 'eat-3 times'],
   ['Commute', 2, 'commute-once a day'],
   ['Watch TV', 2, 'watch tv-daily'],
   ['Sleep', 7, 'sleep-daily']
]);
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/y6e6bkdf/**

---

You can change the legend titles by code once the chart has been drawn :

```js
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
    var svg = document.getElementById('piechart').querySelector('svg'),
        legend = svg.querySelectorAll('g')[1].querySelectorAll('text');
    legend[0].textContent = 'work-daily';
    legend[1].textContent = 'eat-3 times';
    legend[2].textContent = 'commute-once a day';
    legend[3].textContent = 'watch tv-daily';
    legend[4].textContent = 'sleep-daily';
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/w4weh1qy/**

[image]

Sorry if this answer seems weird or exaggerated, but sad to say I dont know any other way to change the titles of a piechart legend.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but you code changes text in legends. I want to change text in pie chart slices.

Comment: @YasirSiddiqui, apparently I cannot read english :( If your concern just is the tooltips, then the feature is natively supported - see updated answer.